# Error: createConnection requires an instance of Request, got [object Object] - Angular2, SytemJs

Tags: angular, karma-runner, systemjs

I'm hitting an issue when trying to MockBackends with Angular2, SystemJs. I'm wanting to test various states of my service methods, but I keep getting the error (Error: createConnection requires an instance of Request, got [object Object]). I can't see any 404s' from Systemjs either. I tried a unit test straight out of the Angular2 docs as that does not work either:

What else should I check?

-- my test

```
it('should get a response', () => {
    let connection; //this will be set when a new connection is emitted from the backend.
    let text; //this will be set from mock response
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {provide: Http, useFactory: (backend, options) => {
            return new Http(backend, options);
        }, deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]}]);
    let backend = injector.get(MockBackend);
    let http = injector.get(Http);
    backend.connections.subscribe(c => connection = c);
    http.request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').subscribe(res => {
        text = res.text();
    });

    console.log('text: ', text);

    connection.mockRespond(new Response({body: [{'id': 1}]}));

    expect(text).toBeDefined();

});
```

-- my service call

```
 return this._http.get(this.url)
            .map(res => res.json());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's

`import {ResponseOptions} from '@angular/http';
(...)
connection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: [{'id': 1}]})));`

the constructor of Response expects it's argument wraped in ResponseOptions ;-)

P.S.: updated the buggy sample in master branch a few days ago but doc still uses an old tagged one. The new Sample can already be found on github: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/@angular/http/testing/mock_backend.ts

Comment: Hi @E. Hein, I made the change as per your post but I still have the exact same issue. I only changed the line you recommended as I already had the ResponseOptions API included. Any other ideas what I need to look at?

Comment: Good morning Jimi, tried the sample myself and it worked as expected: [see connection-response.spec.ts](http://plnkr.co/edit/KWBwBfByHlkFmYlKRcPW?p=preview). Which version of angular did you use? (don't think it's caused by the karma-runner) PS.: obviously we live in different time zones ^^

Comment: I was using 2.3.0, that must have been the issue. I have made the upgrade, there seems to be an issue with the path of something. My tests don't run because of this issue, any ideas for a work around? at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/jspm_packages/npm/zone
.js@0.7.4/dist/zone.js:293:27) [<root>]
        Error loading http://localhost:9876/base/process.js as "process" from http://localhost:9
876/base/jspm_packages/npm/@angular/compiler@2.4.1/testing/../bundles/compiler.umd.js'